# Undefined jQuery error in browserify/gulp build

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I have a problem loading `jquery-ui` in a project that's built with browserify via gulp. In my code, I have:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";
```

The error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. Looking at the jquery-ui code at the point the error occurs, I see:

```js
( function( factory ) {
  if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define( [ "jquery", "./version" ], factory );
  } else {
  // Browser globals
    factory( jQuery );   // <<--- error raised here
  }
}( function( $ ) {
...
```

The core issue is that, while the import of `jquery` has defined `$`, it has not set the global `jQuery` variable.

I've seen a lot of solutions to similar issues involving creating a shim for loading jQuery, but this problem seems different. It's not that jQuery is not being loaded (otherwise `$` would also be undefined), it's that jquery-ui is expecting `jQuery` as a global alias.

I've also seen a lot of suggestions to manually set `window.jQuery = $`, or similar. This also doesn't work in my case, because the bundle of code that is being run is created by browserify, so I don't get to control the order in which modules are being created, so it's unclear to me where in my code I would put such a statement.

For reference, my gulp task is:

```js
browserify(
  "./app/es/app.es",
  {
    debug: true,
  }
)
.transform(babel)
.on("error", function(err) { gutil.log(err); this.emit("end"); })
.pipe(source("build.js"))
.pipe(buffer())
.pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
.pipe(gulp.dest("./build/js"));
```

I have tried inserted a `browserify-shim` transform with the following config:

```js
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "jQuery"
},
```

but it didn't change the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that after transformation by babel, the statement `import` rises to the top:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
import 'jquery-ui';
```

**=>**

```
'use strict';

var _jquery = require('jquery');

var _jquery2 = _interopRequireDefault(_jquery);

require('jquery-ui');

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { 
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; 
}

window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```

Possible solutions:

1) Use `require` instead `import`:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');
```

2) Use the additional wrapper over `jquery`:

**_jquery.js**:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;

export default $;
```

**app.es**:

```
import "./_jquery.js";
import "jquery-ui";
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of what the Babel transform is doing with the `import` statements, so thank you!